# Get drupal user id in a page residing a sub directory

Tags: php, session, drupal, drupal-7

I have read [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056491/drupal-session-user-id-for-independent-script)

Drupal is installed in my local machine and works fine. I have created a static page inside a directory in the drupal installation.
Like `http://localhost/usertest/userts.php`

If the page moved to `root` directory it works but when I move the page to `usertest` or any other directory it is not working.

**Directory structure :**
`root` - drupal installed directory containing all the drupal files including `includes, modules, sites` etc.
`usertest` - sub directory of root.

**Code :**
What my `userts.php` page contains is :

```
<?php 
$currdir=getcwd();
chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
require_once("./includes/bootstrap.inc");
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION);
global $user;
chdir($currdir);


?>
<p>USER VAR :</p>
<?php print_r( $user ); ?>
```

**OUTPUT :**
The out put is given as anonymous user though I logged in :

```
USER VAR :
stdClass Object ( [uid] => 0 [hostname] => 127.0.0.1 [roles] => Array ( [1] => anonymous user ) [session] => [cache] => 0 )
```

But if I remove `chdir` part and move the file to `root` directory and access it 
like `http://localhost/userts.php` then it gives me the current user object output.

I could not figure out what I have missed here. Can anyone help on this ?

Comment: @QuickSilver My requirement is to get only the current user to a page. And do some customization which is outside the Drupal. So a module is heavy for my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `DRUPAL_ROOT`

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/bootstrap.inc");
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION);
```

**Edit://**

Having quickly been playing with this myself, the session won't load your user property properly because the change in `$base_url`

You could fix this by using this code, before you initialise the DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP

```
global $base_url;
// Assuming your drupal installation lives in the DOCUMENT_ROOT
//  -- Which yours does
$base_url = (array_key_exists('HTTPS', $_SERVER) ? 'https://' : http://') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

Comment: Not working. It is giving some errors like : `No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\includes\bootstrap.inc on line 1009`

Comment: So where is your extracted drupal directory?

Comment: Drupal is installed in the `web root` or / directory. Inside the `root` I have created a new folder named `usertest`. The `userts.php` is in that `usertest` directory.

Comment: Are you saying there is no includes/ folder living in C:\wamp\www ?

Comment: It is there. No error in the code I have posted. My code works but the user object is not populated with current user data. It get populated as anonymous. My guess is something wrong when we call `drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION)` code in sub directory of the drupal installation.

Comment: Edited my answer, please try that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13410/discussion-between-shantha-kumara-and-rawkode)